# Successive inheritance of Lists

Tags: java, list, inheritance, arraylist

I have a List structure setup as such:

```
List<List<Value>> l = new RowList();
```

which gives a `"Type mismatch: Cannot convert from RowList to List<List<Value>>"` error. The implementation is as follows:

```
public class RowList extends ArrayList<ValueList>
public class ValueList extends ArrayList<Value>
```

Value is an object in my codebase. Why does this not work? When I have this instead, everything works fine:

```
public class RowList extends ArrayList<List<Value>>
```

For the college assignment I am working on, code that our lecturer has written works by calling a method that returns a `List<List<Value>>` within my code, and then adding `List<Value>` to that list. As the program is meant to implement a database, there are a number of requirements, such as key values not occurring more than once etc. To check that this isn't happening, I need to be able to have a ValueList class or something similar so I can extend the `add()` method to check these requirements.

It now sounds like it's not the correct way to do things, but I don't really have any choice in the matter, as we're not allowed to alter the code that does this. I believe the idea is that it makes us think about generics.

Comment: Terminology note - "multiple inheritance" is usually reserved for the case where one class inherits from two or more bases. In Java, this is only supported if all but one of the "bases" are interfaces so Java is normally considered not to support multiple inheritance, whereas C++ does (and Java specifically chose not to copy that). Having chains of inheritance isn't normally called "multiple inheritance", so calling it "multiple inheritance" is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Steve314 I've changed it to "Successive inheritance": hopefully that's less ambiguous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bad idea to create subclasses of the collections in the first place. Stick with the standard implementations, and use composition rather than inheritance.

Now to understand why this doesn't compile, here's why, with a short example. Suppose what you want to do is possible and compiles, you could then do:

```
RowList rowList = new RowList();
List<List<Value>> listOfLists = rowList;
listOfLists.add(new LinkedList<Value>());
```

And although RowList is supposed to hold instances of `ValueList` only, you would then have a `LinkedList<Value>` inside, ruining the type-safety and correctness of the program.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your first statement (don't subclass collections)? With a link, if possible? Thanks.

Comment: See http://books.google.fr/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=effective+java+composition&source=bl&ots=yYIoLmp4M_&sig=1rtWUGRN7uFUaIlWwGSYbndOeag&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=Lx-fUcn3CvGp7Abes4CQCQ&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20composition&f=false

Comment: @JBNizet My problem is that this assignment requires a List<List<Value>> to be returned that another class can then add/remove elements to/from. I need to be able to intercept these adds and removes to check for validity. If I use composition, then I have no way of doing this.

Comment: Good reference, thank you @JBNizet. Although I still think, that extending classes, e.g. `ArrayList` to add functionality is a good way to work - if it is within a limited scope, as mentioned in Effective Java.

Comment: Using composition is the only way to do this without breaking the List contract. A List is not supposed to reject any added element. Wrap your list into a custom class providing an add() method that throws some InvalidObjectException. Don't extend List to do that: you would break the Liskov principle. Moreover, using inheritance is a sure way to fail, and to have code that breaks when using the next version of the JDK, because there are any ways to add elements to a list (add, addAll, the iterator, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, `RowList` is not a `List<List<Value>>`, so that `List<List<Value>> l = new RowList();` is not valid

Just like you cannot do this:

```
List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

There are several choices for you:

Change declaration of l to be List:

```
List<ValueList> l = new RowList();
```

or making use of wildcard:

```
List<? extends List<Value>> l = new RowList();
```

---

Edit: Although it can be solved by the above approach, your design should be better refactored.  I think you are trying to use inheritance to do something like `typedef` in C/C++, but the side effect of using inheritance to simulate typedef is big (at least in Java) and you should think twice before doing that.  I am not saying you shouldn't use inheritance if it really make sense (i.e. you really want `ValueList` is-a `List<ValueList>` ).  However it seems to me that you are doing so simply to save you typing `List<Value>` instead of introducing a meaningful type.